# How can I get the dropbox short url from Dropbox Chooser?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there a way to get the short url for sharing a document through the Dropbox Chooser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unlike the [Dropbox Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares), the [Dropbox Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser) doesn't offer the ability to get short URLs.

Of course, this doesn't prevent you from using your preferred URL shortener after the fact.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's back: create link, click the Twitter icon, copy db.tt-link, dismiss the Twitter-message (see dropbox forums https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=60222).

Comment: Not quite the same, but definitely something!

Comment: So to get the short link, you're forced to have a Twitter account??